# Imprimir las primeras letras de una frase

Tags: javascript

Necesito imprimir las primeras letras de varias frases del siguiente ejemplo.

```
var uno = "primera frase";
var dos = "segunda frase";
var tres = "ultima frase";
var lista = [uno, dos, tres];
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es esto :

'uno' = pf
 , 'dos' = sf
 , 'tres' = uf

Lo estoy intenando hacer de esta forma pero me saca las primeras letras de cada frase.

```
var uno = "primera frase";
var dos = "segunda frase";
var tres = "ultima frase";
var lista = [uno, dos, tres];

resultado = "";

for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; resultado += lista[i][0], i++);

alert(resultado); // Imprime 'psu'.
```

Comment: debes hacer un split por cada iteracion y seleccionar el primer caracter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tal y como lo tienes te está devolviendo sólo la primera letra de la frase.

Te dejo 3 ejemplos de cómo podrías hacerlo (existen muchas más):

1. Con un simple bucle `for` doble:

```js
let uno = "primera frase";
let dos = "segunda frase";
let tres = "ultima frase";
let lista = [uno, dos, tres];

let resultado = "";

for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
  //Dividimos cada frase en varias palabras
  let aux = lista[i].split(' ');
  //Recorremos la frase dividida y obtenemos el primer caracter de cada palabra
  for(let j = 0; j<aux.length;j++){
    resultado += aux[j].substring(0,1);
  }  
  lista[i] = resultado;
  resultado = "";
}

console.log(lista); // Obtiene array con las primeras letras de las palabras
```

2. Con una expresión regular:

```js
let uno = "primera frase";
let dos = "segunda frase";
let tres = "ultima frase";
let lista = [uno, dos, tres];
    
let resultado2 = "";

for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
  //Buscamos la primera letra de cada palabra (\w)
  let aux = lista[i].match(/\b(\w)/g);
  lista[i] = aux.join('');
}

console.log(lista);
```

3. Utilizando las [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/prototype) (`reduce`, en este caso)

```js
let uno = "primera frase";
let dos = "segunda frase";
let tres = "ultima frase";
let lista = [uno, dos, tres];
    
let resultado3 = "";

for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
  //Dividimos la frase en palabras y recorremos cada uno de esos arrays haciendo un slice de 0,1 para obtener la primera letra de cada palabra
  let aux = lista[i].split(' ').reduce((r,w)=> resultado3+=w.slice(0,1),'')
}

console.log(resultado3);
```

**Edito**: Devuelvo en los dos primeros ejemplos un array con las primeras letras de cada palabra

Answer (score 6):

La solución es primero encontrar para una frase las palabras, para poder entonces encontrar la primera letra de cada una:

```js
let frase = 'En un lugar de la Mancha';

let palabras= frase.split(/\s+/);
console.log(palabras);
```

Para eso puedes usar el método `split`, que trocea un string usando como separador el parámetro que le pases (es una expresión regular, podrías poner un espacio en blanco o `\s`, que es un espacio, un tabulador, nueva línea, nueva página...

Luego te puedes quedar con la primera letra de cada palabra:

```js
let frase = 'En un lugar de la Mancha';

let palabras= frase.split(/\s+/);

//array de primeras letras
let primerasLetras= palabras.map(palabra => palabra[0]);

let unionDeLetras=primerasLetras.join('');

console.log(unionDeLetras);
```

El método `map` devuelve un array con el mismo número de elementos que el original, pero cada elemento es el resultado de aplicar al elemento original la función que le pases como parámetro. En este caso es una función que dado un string, devuelve el primer carácter.

El método join une los elementos en un único string, usando el parámetro que le pases como unión. Podría ser una coma, un guión o un espacio.

Y ahora hacemos esto para cada frase, uniendo los resultados parciales:

```js
let frases = ['En un lugar de la Mancha','Once upon a time', 'A buen entendedor pocas palabras bastan'];


function primerasLetras(frase) {
  let palabras= frase.split(/\s+/);
  //array de primeras letras
  let primerasLetras= palabras.map(palabra => palabra[0]);
  return primerasLetras.join('');
}

let letras= frases.map(primerasLetras);

console.log(letras);

console.log(letras.join(''));
```

Comment: Muchas respuestas sólo te ponen un código al puedes hacer `copy/paste`. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicar cómo funciona el tuyo. +1

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar el método `split`:

```js
    var uno = "primera frase";
    var dos = "segunda frase";
    var tres = "ultima frase";
    var lista = [uno, dos, tres];
    
    var resultado = "";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
    
        var array_palabras = lista[i].split(" ");

        for(var j = 0; j < array_palabras.length; j++){
          resultado += array_palabras[j][0];
        }
    }
    console.log(resultado); //Imprime 'pfsfuf'
```

> El método `split` permite separar una cadena según el caracter que le
>   indiques, separandolo en iteraciones de array.

Y con un bucle for anidado consigues iterar en el array creado apartir del metodo `split`

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución imprime el console.log del resultado que querés obtener! Por cada elemento del array que obtenga de la posición cero, los dos primeros caracteres de cada palabra, y luego un push a un nuevo array para guardar el resultado.
Espero que te sirva!

```
function newFunction(){
    var uno = "primera frase";
    var dos = "segunda frase";
    var tres = "ultima frase";
    var lista = [uno, dos, tres];
    var resultadoArray = []

    resultado = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

        hola= lista[i].split(' ')
        for (let i = 0; i< hola.length ; i++){
            resultado = hola[i].substring(0, 2)
            resultadoArray.push(resultado)
        }


        console.log(resultado)


    }
    return resultadoArray;    
}

console.log(newFunction());
```

Comment: Tu respuesta no hace lo que pide la pregunta, solo muestra las dos primeras letras de cada frase (de primera frase pone pr) y lo que el usuario pide es la primera letra de cada palabra de la frase (de la primera frase habría que encontrar pf)

Comment: Hola Emilio, acá va el código mejorado! saludos!

Comment: Mucho mejor, todavía tiene dos pequeños errores. La variable i se usa en ambos ciclos. Traes de a 2 letras por cada palabra. Pruébalo. Puedes probarlo online en https://rextester.com/VWNTI2772

Comment: Muchas gracias Emilio! lo pruebo y te aviso!